# Как найти отправленные сообщения через smtp в mail.com, python

Tags: python, smtp, mail.ru, smtplib

Я написал код который отправляет сообщения с помощью smtp через mail.ru, всё прекрасно работает, но у меня не получается найти отправленные письма на самой почте mail.ru, подскажите пожалуйста где это можно найти, я понимаю что можно чуть дописать и вести собственную статистику на своём устройстве, но всё же если есть мысли поделитесь

```
import openpyxl
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import os

# Данные для работы с отправкой сообщений (переменные переделаны в константы)


REPORTLOCATION = 'reportsever0923'
DISPATCHDATA = 'Subscriber_list.xlsx'



SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.mail.ru'
SMTP_PORT = 465
SENDER_EMAIL = 'почта.ru' 
SENDER_PASSWORD = "пароль"
SUBJECT = 'Ежемесячная отправка отчётов'





def xl_otpravka(xl_files,tsjPOCHT):
    # Создание сообщения
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = SENDER_EMAIL
    msg['To'] = tsjPOCHT
    msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT

    # Добавление файлов
    for filepath in xl_files:
        filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
        with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
            part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
            part.set_payload(f.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
        msg.attach(part)

    # Отправка письма
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
    server.login(SENDER_EMAIL, SENDER_PASSWORD)
    server.sendmail(SENDER_EMAIL, tsjPOCHT, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()

def rar_otpravka(DataRARFF, inspectorPOCHT):
    # Создание сообщения
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = SENDER_EMAIL
    msg['To'] = inspectorPOCHT
    msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT

    # Добавление файлов
    for filepath in DataRARFF:
        filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
        with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
            part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
            part.set_payload(f.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
        msg.attach(part)

    # Отправка письма
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
    server.login(SENDER_EMAIL, SENDER_PASSWORD)
    server.sendmail(SENDER_EMAIL, inspectorPOCHT, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()


def WorkBookSheet(DISPATCHDATA):
    wbs = openpyxl.load_workbook(DISPATCHDATA).worksheets[3]
    return wbs

def main():
    wbs = WorkBookSheet(DISPATCHDATA)
    i = 0
    k = 1
    DataRARF = []
    


    while True:
        i += 1
        cell = wbs.cell(row=i, column=k).value



        if cell is None:
        
            
            if  not DataRARF:
                print(f'Столбец c ячейками {cell} пуст\n \
                        Проверьти правильно ли указана папка')

            else:
                DataRARFF = []
                for подсписок in DataRARF:
                    for элемент in подсписок:
                        DataRARFF.append(элемент)




                rar_otpravka(DataRARFF, inspectorPOCHT)
                print(DataRARFF)
                DataRARF = []
                inspectorPOCHT = ''

            i = 1
            k += 1
            cell = wbs.cell(row=i, column=k).value



        cellFont = wbs.cell(row=i, column=k).font.b


        if cell is None:
            break
        if cellFont:
            continue
        
        
        # Парсинг ячейки
        ListCell = cell.split(":")
        inspectorPOCHT =ListCell[0]
        tsjPOCHT =ListCell[1]
        xlf = ListCell[2]
        rarf = ListCell[3]
        rar_files = zip_files = []
        xl_files = []

    # Поиск rar.zip файлов
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(REPORTLOCATION):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith(".rar") and rarf in file:
                    rar_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
                elif file.endswith(".rar") and xlf in file:
                    zip_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))

        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(REPORTLOCATION):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith(".zip") and rarf in file:
                    rar_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
                elif file.endswith(".zip") and xlf in file:
                    rar_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    # Поиск xl файлов
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(REPORTLOCATION):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith(".xlsx") and rarf in file:
                    xl_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
                elif file.endswith(".xlsx") and xlf in file:
                    xl_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))

        
        if not zip_files and not rar_files:
            pass
        elif zip_files is rar_files:
            DataRARF.append(rar_files)
        elif zip_files == [] and rar_files is not []:
            DataRARF.append(rar_files)
        elif rar_files == [] and zip_files is not []:
            DataRARF.append(zip_files)
        else:
            pass
        
        
        
        
        if xl_files == []:
            print(f'Ссылаясь на ячейку {wbs.cell(row=i, column=k)} не нашли нужных эксель файлов')
        else:
            xl_otpravka(xl_files, tsjPOCHT)
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: никак и нигде. если ваш mail-клиент не копирует сообщение в нужный каталог на сервере, то сообщения там и не будет.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо огромное, вы помогли мне сдвинуться с мёртвой точки
это похоже на костыль, но основную функцию выполняет 
    server_draft = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
    server_draft.login(SENDER_EMAIL, SENDER_PASSWORD)
    server_draft.select('Drafts')
    server_draft.append('Drafts', '', None, msg.as_bytes())
    server_draft.quit()

Comment: уточнение к предыдущему комментарию: smtp-протокол вообще не про копирование. копировать сообщение в хранилище (и из него) нынче модно (насколько я в курсе) по протоколу imap (раньше боолее популярным был pop3).

Answer (score 0):

Вот код который позволяет получить себе же отправленное сообщение, лучше конечно создать sql и записывать туда данные, но всё же

```
def xl_otpravka(DataRARFF,inspectorPOCHT):
    # Создание сообщения
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = SENDER_EMAIL
    msg['To'] = inspectorPOCHT
    msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT



    # Добавление файлов
    for filepath in DataRARFF:
        filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
        with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
            part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
            part.set_payload(f.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
        msg.attach(part)

    text_part = MIMEText(outmassage, 'plain')
    msg.attach(text_part)


    # Отправка письма
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
    server.login(SENDER_EMAIL, SENDER_PASSWORD)
    server.sendmail(SENDER_EMAIL, inspectorPOCHT, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()

    
    message = f"Адрес на который было отправленно письмо:<{inspectorPOCHT}>"
    text_part = MIMEText(message, 'plain')
    msg.attach(text_part)


    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
    server.login(SENDER_EMAIL, SENDER_PASSWORD)
    server.sendmail(SENDER_EMAIL, SENDER_EMAIL, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```